# Show that if $\mathfrak{p} \subset R$ is a prime ideal, then $S = R \setminus \mathfrak{p}$ is multiplicatively closed.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization, integral-domain

Here is the question that I want to answer:

Let $R$ be an integral domain with field of fractions $K,$ and let $S \subset R \setminus \{0\}$ be a multiplicatively closed subset.

Show that if $\mathfrak{p} \subset R$ is a prime ideal, then  $S = R \setminus \mathfrak{p}$ is multiplicatively closed.

**My thoughts**

I know that if $R$ is a commutative ring with unity then the proper ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime iff $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is an integral domain. but how can this help me in my proof? the set $S$ is defined as the setminus not the quotient.

Could anyone help me in solving this please?

This is the definition I am using for multiplicatively closed set.

**Definition:**  A set $S \subset R \setminus \{0\}$ is multiplicatively closed if $x,y \in S \implies xy \in S.$

Comment: I mean, if you look closely, the definition of prime ideal *is* that its complement is non-empty and multiplicatively closed.

Comment: I know that in a commutative ring $R$ with unity, a proper ideal  $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime iff if $ab \in \mathfrak{p} $ then either $a \in \mathfrak{p}$ or $b \in \mathfrak{p}.$ Bu tI can not see how that will help me also. .... could you please explain more to me either in an answer or here in comments. @Gae.S.

Comment: I won't in either. Feel free to keep reading until you realise that I am right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reflect on this, you will start to see that this is true by definition of prime ideals: They are exactly those ideals into which you cannot multiply from outside. Whether you state it as
\begin{align*}
 xy ∈ \mathfrak p &\implies& x ∈ \mathfrak p &~~~\text{or}~~~ y ∈ \mathfrak p, &\quad \text{or as} \\
 xy ∈ R \setminus \mathfrak p &\impliedby&  x ∈ R \setminus \mathfrak p &~~\text{and}~~  y ∈ R \setminus \mathfrak p 
\end{align*}
is just a matter of giving contrapositions of each other. The latter line says that $S = R \setminus \mathfrak p$ is mutliplicatively closed, which is what you want to prove.

By the way: You could in principle also kind of use the fact that $R' = R / \mathfrak p$ is an integral domain. This means that $S' = R' \setminus \{0\}$ is multiplicatively closed. So as $S = R \setminus \mathfrak p = \mathrm{pr}^{-1} (R' \setminus \{0\}) = \mathrm{pr}^{-1}(S')$ is the preimage of a multiplicatively closed set under a ring homomorphism (so in particular under a multiplicative homomorphism), $S$ itself is multiplicatively closed too. This exposes the core insight behind this to realizing that for a commutative ring $R'$
$$R' ~\text{is integral domain} \iff R'\setminus \{0\} ~\text{is multiplicatively closed},$$
but this line of reasoning is disproportionate to the puzzle at hand.

Comment: How  $R'$ being an integral domain leads to $S'$ is multiplicatively closed .... I can not see that .... could you please explain that to me?

Comment: Think about yourself, you will get it.

Comment: I know trivially by the definition of an integral domain it is multiplicatively closed. and because it has no zero divisors then if we removed the zero from it it will still be a multiplicatively closed set. ok that make sense

Comment: I do not understand this line " So as $S = R \setminus \mathfrak p = \mathrm{pr}^{-1} (R' \setminus \{0\}) = \mathrm{pr}^{-1}(S')$ " why we need to speak abou t the preimage and why the primage of $S'$ is S

Comment: Can you  recab the answer for me as I feel like you are telling me a lot of ideas.

Comment: I think I got your idea ... the whole answer is in the contrapositive part. Am I correct?

Comment: @Math Yeah, you seem to get it. I provided two answers (in case that hasn’t been clear). The second answer hinges on understanding how structures relate under homomorphisms. If you don’t get the second answer immediately, you don’t need to understand it now for what you want – however, if you want to study algebra, you will soon need to reason like that without any effort, so trying to understand the second answer may be worthwhile. I won’t explain it further for now. You will probably clearly understand it all pretty soon by yourself. If not, feel free to ask again after a while.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: As with many statements like this, it's useful to proceed by way of contradiction. Assume that $x,y\in S$, but $xy\not\in S$. What does this mean about inclusions in $\mathfrak p$? Can you use that to show that this contradicts the definition of prime ideal?

Comment: I do not see any relation between $\mathfrak{p}$ and $S$ in the question. So I do  not know how to answer your first question.

Comment: I know that in a commutative ring $R$ with unity, a proper ideal  $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime iff if $ab \in \mathfrak{p} $ then either $a \in \mathfrak{p}$ or $b \in \mathfrak{p}.$ Bu tI can not see how that will help me also.

Comment: @Math $S$ is defined to be everything in $R$ that's not in $\mathfrak p$.

Comment: Yes I know that ... and we need a product to be in $\mathfrak{p}$ at first to define primeness. but then what?

Comment: Oh so the answer to your first question is that implies that $\mathfrak {p} $ is prime.

Comment: The primeness condition is satisfied vacously